# What's the name of the game about LARP de-briefings?

Tags: product-identification, larp, norwegian-style

Players sit or stand in circle.
Each player gets a note with something they must include in their de-briefing.
Then, in order, they start telling what they liked or didn't like about this LARP that's supposed to be just happened.
Whatever a player says becomes true for everyone else.
The last two players play the role of the organizers of the LARP.

It's a game inspired by nordic LARPs and I think it's by someone involved with jeepforms, but I'm not sure.

What's the name of this game?

Comment: Do you know if this is a print product or not? (It sounds like it could easily be a homebrewed game made by a LARPer with a taste for meta.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found it by chance.

The game is called **Retrospect**, by Even Tømte.
It's one of the 17 RPGs featured in the *Norwegian Style* anthology.